# training an alpha value for ridge regression

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, regression

I have the following code which runs a simple Ridge regression:

```
for col in cols:                      #zscore normalization
    df[col] = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std(ddof=0)
y = df['SPXR_{}D'.format(horizon)]    #my dependent variable (future market returns)
x = df[cols]                          #a bunch of variables that predict market returns
model = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.5) #ridge regression, guess & check based alpha
res = model.fit(x, y)
```

I have read that using the first half of my data to find an alpha is the easiest approach, however how is this possible?

Comment: Yeah the general way to find a good alpha is [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)), where for *each alpha*, you repeatedly partition your data, train on the first partition, test on the other partition, and find the average test error. So the result of k-fold or leave-one-out cross-validation is a plot of average test error against alpha, and you pick the alpha that gave you the lowest cross-validated error. Does that make sense? (I'll double-check, I'm sure scikit-learn has a way to automate cross-validation and find the best alpha for you.)

Comment: See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me point you in 2 possible directions.

1) **Cross validation**:

- [RidgeCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html) - Just a convenient wrapper combining GridSearchCV and Ridge. Fit the model and check the attribute _alpha.

2) **Bayesian approach**:

- [Bayesian Ridge Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html#sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge) - Fit the model and compute _lambda / _alpha.